# wcf message logging uploading files

Tags: wcf, logging, size, message, packet

I'm sending files from clients to a server using WCF with different bindings. I need to know the sizes of the packets that the client send. How should I configure diagnostics in the config?? Or how can I view this?? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To enable diagnostics, edit *.config* file

```
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="sdt" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="App_Data\WCF.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

Then you can open *.svclog* file with *[Microsoft Service Trace Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms732023.aspx)*

**See also**:

- [Configuring Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms733025.aspx) at MSDN
- [Administration and Diagnostics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms731055.aspx) at MSDN
- [Configuring Message Logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms730064.aspx) at MSDN

Comment: I enabled message logging with all messages (malformed, transport, service) and tracing too but I can'tview the packet size. Help!!

Comment: Turned on message logging, so the messages themselves get logged too (with properties such as size...)

Comment: It's turned on but where should I put that property??